# Explicit delete and new vs using a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, delete-operator

I have a callback passed to an async function that is only responsible for deleting a pointer passed to the async function.
How should I delete the pointer:

1. By using an explicit delete.
2. By creating a unique_ptr that will delete the object.

Same question also for the creation of the object - should I use new or create an unique_ptr and immediately release it.

```
MyClass* myClass = make_unique<MyClass>().release();
AsyncFunc(myClass, [myClass](){std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(myClass)}
```

vs

```
MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
AsyncFunc(myClass, [myClass](){delete myClass;)}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `AsyncFunc`?

Comment: If `AsyncFunc` takes ownership of the memory for `myClass`, then it should ideally accept a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` to semantically indicate that it does so.  In this case you don't need to pass a callback to delete the pointer, it is deleted as soon as `AsyncFunc` is finished using it.  However, without more information it's difficult to determine what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think there is no need for explicit delete. I wonder what do you want to archieve. It is important how that pointer is CREATED and USED before it is passed to asynchronous delete. std::auto_ptr would do fine job. I think you are solving it from the wrong side. Start at the beginning.

Comment: The line `MyClass* myClass = make_unique<MyClass>().release();` is totally pointless.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

You should do this...

```
auto myClass = make_unique<MyClass>();
// hand out pointers to myClass by using myClass.get() as needed
AsyncFunc([p = std::move(myClass)]{ p.reset(); });
// make sure any pointers to myClass you handed out are unused/gone
// by the time the async func is called
```

This way you never hold ownership via a raw pointer (which, you should never do), and the lambda has ownership of `myClass` because it has been `move`d into the lambda capture.

You could also just leave out the `p.reset()` and let the pointer die when  the lambda dies, which I assume (depending on `AsyncFunc`) is immediately after the lambda is called.

Comment: It doesn't sounds like he wants pass a function to run asynchronously, it sounds like `AsyncFunc` does some unspecified work asynchronously and he wants a function to call to clean up memory afterwards, in which case all he needs is a `std::unique_ptr`.  It's hard to tell what he is trying to do though.

Comment: @David Oh I see, yes I agree on all points - it depends what he is trying to do. It's not clear.

Comment: Is this syntax supported by c++11? It looks like it is only supported in c++14 and I need to use c++11.

Comment: @user844541 well if you can't use c++14 I guess I would do the same thing but with a `shared_ptr`, where the lambda is the sole owner of the `shared_ptr` after it has been copied